# How to throw different errors in a Promise function?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

For testing I want that all code is coveraged and I want to reject different self written errors for each of the steps in this Promise function.

```
function convertToXML(b64DataPara) {

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var b64Data = b64DataPara;

    if(b64Data === '' || b64Data === undefined){
        return reject(new Error(errorMessages.B64Undefined));
    }

    if(typeof b64Data === 'number'){
        return reject(new Error(errorMessages.StringNeededNotNumber));
    }

    // Decode base64 (convert ascii to binary)

    var strData = atob(b64Data);
    
    if (strData === undefined){
        return reject(new Error(errorMessages.invalidCharacterInB64));
    }

    // Convert binary string to character-number array
    var charData = strData.split('').map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0);});

    // Turn number array into byte-array
    var binData = new Uint8Array(charData);

    // Decompress data
    var data = pako.inflate(binData);

    // Convert gunzipped byteArray back to ascii string:
    var xmlData = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(data));

    resolve(xmlData);

})
```

I have two ideas:

1. Wrap each step with an if / else
2. Put all the code inside the Promise function in a try-catch and handle in the catch block all errors with if else and so on.

Both ideas seem not professional to me. So I am wondering whats the best / elegant way to do this. Or do you think all substeps should be inside its own Promise function?

Comment: Currently all your code is inside the Promise executor. Doesn't seem very neat to me - it works but it adds extra nesting which is basically irrelevant. You can make your function `async` and then convert `reject(x)` to `throw ` and `resolve(x)` to `return x`. It would be equivalent to what you have now just no need for extra two sets of brackets around everything as well as an indentation level.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But can I then call the function in this way?:  const dataAsXml = await convertToXML('SomeBase64String);

Comment: `async` functions automatically convert the entire body to a promise and always return it. In effect, it's doing what you're manually doing. Any thrown exceptions would reject, while a return will resolve the promise.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to reconstruct and made q quick test on stackblitz. What did I wrong in that code? Promise writes on console 7 and the async function writes undefined: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rabf8y

Comment: The doesn't need *any* other code - it's already returning a promise. [Here is how the conversion looks](https://jsbin.com/qozecobiva/edit?js,output) (using JSBin just as a code dump). Your `addInAsync` doesn't work because it doesn't return anything - the `return` statement is in the `setTimeout` callback. In general, you should avoid using `setTimeout` like that as it's more confusing when mixing with async code. You can promisify it as an `wait` function like this and then you can make the `addInPromise` and `addInAsync` equivalent: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-slyaqx